# Click event in highcharter treemap (R shiny)

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

Based on the answer to this question: [Highcharter - Clickable Pie Chart - How to get the category name from the slice clicked on a Pie Chart in Shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447974/highcharter-clickable-pie-chart-how-to-get-the-category-name-from-the-slice), I am trying to capture the output of a click event on a highcharter treemap in an R Shiny app.

I think I just need the right name to replace "event.point.name" in this javascript function:

```
function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('treemapclick', event.point.name);}
```

but I am not sure where to look.

Thanks in advance for your generosity!

```r
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(gapminder)


ui <- fluidPage(
  column(12, highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "300px")),
  column(12, textOutput("clicked")))

server <- function(input, output){
  
  click_js <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('treemapclick', event.point.name);}")
  
  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({  
      
        gapminder::gapminder %>%
        filter(year  == 2007) %>% 
        highcharter::data_to_hierarchical(group_vars = c(continent, country), size_var = pop) %>% 
        hchart(type = "treemap") %>% 
        hc_plotOptions(events = list(click = click_js))


  })
  
  output$clicked <- renderText({
    input$treemapclick
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Treemap click event]

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the problem! The issue was not with the event.point.name variable, but with the plot options. Changing it to this:

```
 hc_plotOptions(treemap = list(events = list(click = click_js)))
```

does the trick.

Working reprex:

```r
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(gapminder)


ui <- fluidPage(
  column(12, highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "300px")),
  column(12, textOutput("clicked")))

server <- function(input, output){
  
  click_js <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('treemapclick', event.point.name);}")
  
  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({  
      
        gapminder::gapminder %>%
        filter(year  == 2007) %>% 
        highcharter::data_to_hierarchical(group_vars = c(continent, country), size_var = pop) %>% 
        hchart(type = "treemap") %>% 
        hc_plotOptions(treemap = list(events = list(click = click_js)))

  })
  
  output$clicked <- renderText({input$treemapclick  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Reprex output]